# How to do a popup window like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Take this page as an example: http://download.cnet.com/AD-Stream-Recorder/3000-2168_4-10525870.html

If you try to post a comment, this window pop up and the whole page is locked.

[image: pop up window]

Can anyone tell me how this is done?

Comment: What have you tried? You can always look at the source of the page (or use a tool like firebug).

Comment: I kid... -1 for a bad question. As @WilliamVanRensselaer said, you can always look at the source. Besides these pop ups are very annoying.

Comment: Some of you guys are just so arrogant. This is certainly not so easy by simply looking at the source code. If you dont want to answer this question, you can leave it to others. There are some tricks not so easy for newbies. Even some hint on keyword would be good. Anyway, I will figure it out myself.

Comment: That's exactly why these are *comments*, not answers. "Anyway, I will figure it out myself." - which is what you should have done to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQueryUI dialog for this. Put your dialog in modal mode, and the whole page will be disabled for use. Example http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

If you got your own dialog, and want to disable everything else. Make a div put it on position: fixed, width 100% and height 100%, left 0, top 0. And put the z-index this high that it is below your dialog, but above all other content.